# Javascript array inside array

Tags: javascript

I am creating an array like this:

```
var groupUserCounter=[];
groupUserCounter["asd"]=1;
groupUserCounter["asd2"]=2;
var groupC=[];

for(var key in groupUserCounter) {
   groupC.push(key);
}

console.log(groupC);
```

Output:

```
Array [ "asd", "asd2" ]
```

But I need something like this:

```
Array [ ["asd"], ["asd2"] ]
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push your **key** into **groupC**, you have to push a key array, not just the value.

```
  var groupUserCounter=[];
  groupUserCounter["asd"]=1;
  groupUserCounter["asd2"]=2;
  var groupC=[];

  for(var key in groupUserCounter) {
     groupC.push([key]);
  }

  console.log(groupC);
```

**EDIT**

A more elegant way is using **.keys()** and **.map()** method.

```
  var groupUserCounter=[];
  groupUserCounter["asd"]=1;
  groupUserCounter["asd2"]=2;

  var groupC = Object.keys(groupUserCounter).map(function(elm){
    return [elm]
  });

  console.log(groupC);
```

Comment: no need to make object he can do var groupUserCounter=[] and the same code you have provided

Comment: Yep i've edited the response, but when I use a **for in** loop, i prefer to iterate over an object.

Answer (score 1):

**$.makeArray()** functions returns any object into a native Array.just like below

```
$.each(groupUserCounter, function(index, value) { 
     groupC.push($.makeArray( value));
});
console.log(groupC);//something like this what u expected Array [ ["asd"], ["asd2"] ]
```